# Opening an app using another app

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm just wondering is it possible?
Let's say I wrote an app and I want to use a button to open (from the app I wrote) another app (sing its directory) on my Mac

Any idea where to start off? I've been thinking about NSFileManager but it seems like a wrong way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the methods of `NSWorkspace`. Which method exactly depends a bit on exactly what you want to do. For example, if you have the URL for a document file and you want to open it in the appropriate app, you would use `-openURL:`.

If you just want to open a specific app (and not any particular document), then you should use `-launchAppWithBundleIdentifier:options:additionalEventParamDescriptor:launchIdentifier:`. Using a bundle identifier is the most reliable way to identify the app, rather than using its name or its URL, either of which can be changed.

Comment: Thanks mate! It really helped me!